# Can't Install - grub probe: error: unknown filesystem -- Help?

Tags: installation, grub2, filesystem, live-cd

I can't install Ubuntu on my computer, I'm using a 12.04 LTS LiveCD. I have 2 empty hard drives (500 GB each) and no other operating system's installed. The installer always seems to be stuck at the "copying files" dialog, even though the progress bar is moving forward.The last message by the console window is `Ubiquity: grub probe: error: unknown filesystem`

All the google searches till now have led me to this problem appearing AFTER installation and always followed by a `grub rescue>` which I don't get, I tried creating an Ext3 partition (root "/ ") of the whole drive (with a 16 GB Swap at the end of the drive) because I read that Grub 2 doesn't agree well with Ext4, but I'm still getting the same error, tried to install on sdb instead sda as well but no luck, could I get some help here please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like too big / partition or no /boot partition